# Adams-Bashforth algorithm

Tags: algorithms, numerical-calculus

So i got a project and I've been trying to solve it, but I just don't know how to start, and I haven't found an example similar to this one. So if you could guide me a little bit I would really appreciate it.

Giving the Cauchy 
$$y'=-y^2$$  $$y(0)=1$$

which has the exact solution $y(x)=1/(1+x)$. Using the Adams-Bashforth procedure for $h=0.5$ and $0.25$ solve the problem for the following interval $[0,5]$.

I didn't learned this algorithm in school and online I can't find similar examples, so if you could guide me a bit it would really help me!

Comment: What is your task here? Shall you implement the algorithm in a programming language? Or compute the first couple of steps by hand?

Comment: I have to implement it in MATLAB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to write the recurrence. For example, if you look at AB method with $s=2$, the numerical scheme is the following:

$y_{n+2}=y_{n+1}-\frac{k}{2}f(t_n,y_n) +\frac{3k}{2}f(t_{n+1},y_{n+1})$.

It's a second order method, and you can compute $y_1$ ($y_0$ is of course given, and it's $y_0=1$, since it's the initial data!) with *explicit Euler* method.

In your specific example, $f$ is given by $f(t,y)=f(y)=-y^2$, and $k$ is your step size $h$.

It's just a *for* loop where you update at each time-step $y_{n+1},y_n$.

Comment: function [y t] = abm4(f,a,b,ya,n) h = (b - a) / n; h24 = h / 24;
y(1,:) = ya; t(1) = a;
m = min(3,n);
for i = 1 : m t(i+1) = t(i) + h; s(i,:) = f(t(i), y(i,:)); s2 = f(t(i) + h / 2, y(i,:) + s(i,:) * h /2); s3 = f(t(i) + h / 2, y(i,:) + s2 * h /2); s4 = f(t(i+1), y(i,:) + s3 * h); y(i+1,:) = y(i,:) + (s(i,:) + s2+s2 + s3+s3 + s4) * h / 6; end;
for i = m + 1 : n s(i,:) = f(t(i), y(i,:)); y(i+1,:) = y(i,:) + (55 * s(i,:) - 59 * s(i-1,:) + 37 * s(i-2,:) - 9 * s(i-3,:)) * h24; t(i+1) = t(i) + h; y(i+1,:) = y(i,:) + (9 * f(t(i+1), y(i+1,:)) + 19 * s(i,:) - 5 * s(i-1,:) + s(i-2,:)) * h24; end;